# How to cause tonal accents to replace tittles in TIPA?

Tags: linguistics, tipa

The tittle (dot) in letters like i is replaced by the accent in normal TeX. When TIPA is used to create tonal vowels like í from characters like i and ɨ using `\textipa{\'i}`, the accent is placed *above* the tittle.

How can I cause the accent to replace the tittle?

Comment: the standard markup would be to use  a dotless i so `\'\i` not `\'i` although it is possible to make both work, as is done for the common ones in T1 encoding

Comment: Is there a dotless `ɨ`?